# Using Perl XML::SAX to modify XML documents

Tags: xml, perl, sax

I'm trying to use XML::SAX to modify parts of an XHTML document, however all my attempts have failed.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
package MyHandler;
use strict;
use warnings;

use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);
use Data::Dumper;

sub start_element {
    my $self = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    if( $data->{LocalName} eq 'span') {
        $data->{LocalName} = 'naps';
    }

    $self->SUPER::start_element($data); # GOOD (and easy) !
    #print Dumper($data); 
}

1;

#============================
#Main programm
#============================
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use XML::SAX::Writer;

my $out;

my $o = XML::SAX::Writer->new( Output => \$out );
my $h = MyHandler->new( Handler => $o );
my $p = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => $h);

my $data;
{ local undef $/ }; $data = <DATA>;
$p->parse_string( $data );
print $out;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <form wicket:id="mvpForm">
        <span>Edit Information: </span>
        <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="editForm"/>

        <span>Name: </span>
        <span wicket:id="name"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="nameEdit"/>

        <span>Last Name: </span>
        <span wicket:id="lastName"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="lastNameEdit"/>

        <span>DOB: </span>
        <span wicket:id="dob"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="dobEdit"/>


        <span>Occupation: </span>
        <span wicket:id="occupation"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="occupationEdit"/>


        <span>Gender: </span>
        <span wicket:id="gender"></span>
        <span wicket:id="genderEdit"/>

        <input type="submit" wicket:id="submit"/>

    </form>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

The basic idea is to change every "span" to a "naps" and write the resulting modified XML to STDOUT.

Also, it'd be nice to see if its possible to merge xml chunks using SAX, in other words, if I found a particular element that gets expanded to something else, how can I merge it with the output going to STDOUT?

E.g.
From:

```
<xmltag>
    <expandable/>
</xmltag>
```

To:

```
<xmltag>
    <expanded>
        This is an expanded element
    </expanded>
</xmltag>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question regarding merging/expanding elements, here is a snippet on how to do it with sax:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
package MyHandler;
use strict;
use warnings;

use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use XML::SAX::Writer;

sub start_element {
    my $self = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    if( $data->{LocalName} eq 'expand') {
        $self->{in_include}++;
        my $p = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser( Handler => $self );
        $p->parse_string( "<expanded>This is my expanded tag</expanded>" );
        return;
    }

    #$data->{Attributes} = undef;
    $self->SUPER::start_element($data);
    #print Dumper($data); 
}

sub characters {
    my $self = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    #print "Data is $data->{Data}" if defined $data->{Data}; 
    $self->SUPER::characters($data);
}

sub end_element {
    my ($self, $element) = @_;
    if ($element->{LocalName} eq "expand") {
        $self->{in_include}--;
    } else {
        $self->SUPER::end_element($element);
    }
}

sub start_document { # same for end_document
    my($self, $data) = @_;
    return if($self->{in_include});
    $self->SUPER::start_document($data);
}

sub end_document { # same for end_document
    my($self, $data) = @_;
    return if($self->{in_include});
    $self->SUPER::end_document($data);
}

1;

#============================
#Main programm
#============================
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use XML::SAX::Writer;

my $out;

my $o = XML::SAX::Writer->new( Output => \$out );
my $h = MyHandler->new( Handler => $o );
my $p = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => $h);

my $data;
{ local undef $/ }; $data = <DATA>;
$p->parse_string( $data );
print $out;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <form wicket:id="mvpForm">
        <span>Edit Information: </span>
        <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="editForm"/>

        <span>Name: </span>
        <span wicket:id="name"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="nameEdit"/>

        <span>Last Name: </span>
        <span wicket:id="lastName"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="lastNameEdit"/>

        <span>DOB: </span>
        <span wicket:id="dob"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="dobEdit"/>

        <span>Occupation: </span>
        <span wicket:id="occupation"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="occupationEdit"/>

        <span>Gender: </span>
        <span wicket:id="gender"></span>
        <span wicket:id="genderEdit"/>

        <input type="submit" wicket:id="submit"/>

        <expand/>

    </form>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<expand/>` tag will be replaced by `<expanded>This is my expanded tag</expanded>`.

Basically all is needed is to create a new parser and hand it a file/string to be parsed. However, note that there are a couple of gotchas. The first one is to stop propagating the event where you have intercepted the tag to be expanded. In other words don't call $self->SUPER::start/end_element whenever expanding/nesting tags, that will prevent the replaced tag to end up in the output. Second, it's required to intercept start_document/end_document and skip calling the parent for those ones, otherwise the following error will be produced:

> Trying to pop context without push context at /usr/share/perl5/XML/NamespaceSupport.pm line 79,  chunk 1.

In other words some clean up fails:

> This message is being triggered because XML::NamespaceSupport does some initialisation on a start_document event and some cleanup on an end_document event. The problem is that with your code there will be a pair of these events for the main document and a nested pair for each included document. When the second end_document event occurs, there is nothing to clean up - hence the message. 
>   
>   [Taken from here](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.perl.xml/2003-10/msg00030.html)

Answer (score 2):

SAX is not the best tool for trivial changes like this. Consider a DOM implementation.

```
use strictures;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(…);

for my $e ($dom->findnodes('//*')) {
    $e->setNodeName('naps') if 'span' eq $e->nodeName;
    if ('expandable' eq $e->nodeName) {
        $e->setNodeName('expanded');
        $e->appendText('This is an expanded element');
    }
}
print $dom->toString; # ->toFile
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too, the only consern is how memory intensive this would be.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.39/Twig.pm)-based solution, which I find easier to use than SAX (but then I might be a tad biased ;--). It is very memory efficient as only 1 `span` (or `expandable`) element is kept in memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { span       => sub { $_->set_tag( 'naps')->flush; },
                                expandable => sub { XML::Twig::Elt->new( expanded => 'this is an expanded element')->print; },
                              },
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
              )
          ->parsefile( \*DATA);
__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <form wicket:id="mvpForm">
        <span>Edit Information: </span>
        <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="editForm"/>

        <span>Name: </span>
        <span wicket:id="name"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="nameEdit"/>

        <span>Last Name: </span>
        <span wicket:id="lastName"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="lastNameEdit"/>

        <span>DOB: </span>
        <span wicket:id="dob"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="dobEdit"/>


        <span>Occupation: </span>
        <span wicket:id="occupation"></span>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="occupationEdit"/>


        <span>Gender: </span>
        <span wicket:id="gender"></span>
        <span wicket:id="genderEdit"/>

        <input type="submit" wicket:id="submit"/>

    </form>

<xmltag>
    <expandable/>
</xmltag>

</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: at least for the user of the module ;--)

Comment: that looks fairly simple and convenient. I tried to stay away from dom/tree based solutions as they are usually more memory intensive, but twig is a nice balance between the convenience of dom and lightness of sax. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the **Writer** picks element name from Key **Name** and not **LocalName**. So instead of modifying **LocalName** modify **Name** to have desired results.

```
if( $data->{LocalName} eq 'span') {
    $data->{LocalName} = 'naps';
}
```

change it to

```
if( $data->{LocalName} eq 'span') {
    $data->{Name} = 'naps';
}
```

Comment: What about adding that text node?

Comment: I don't think SAX as it is supports adding node. Probably using dirty ways!

Comment: Thanks, that was a little unexpected tho :). Yes looks like the best way to do that would be to create another sax parser once an expandable node is found, but then how do you merge it back with the main processing pipeline? I'll experiment some more, perhaps there is a solution after all.